# transpose part of a table with Python

Tags: python

I need help building a script in python transposing part of a csv as in the example below:

```
[[0A,0B,0C,0D,0E,0F]
[01,02,03,04,05,06]
[07,08,09,10,11,12]
[13,14,15,16,17,18]
[19,20,21,22,23,24]]
```

it:

```
[[0A, 0B, 0C]
[01,02,03]
[01,02,04]
[01,02,05]
[01,02,06]
[07,08,09]
[07.08, 10]
[07,08,11]
 .
 .
 .
[19,20,24]]
```

Has anyone done this kind of transposition of a csv / xls with python?

Comment: thats not a transpose ...

Comment: Do you actually have a list of lists? And that doesn't actually appear to be a transposition operation, how do you got from your input to your output?

Comment: You may incorrectly used the terminology. Can you describe "how" do you intend to do actuallY?

Comment: I put the example, but I'll speak real data to become more direct. I'm working with data from nielsen in excel, the first columns aggregations and last columns are the dates, so I want to just have a date column and repeat aggregations of columns for each of the dates. it is as if the cols were: agreg1, agreg2, date1, date2, ..., date24 and just want agreg1, agreg2 and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of list slicing, nested list comprehensions, and `itertools.chain`:

```
M = [['0A','0B','0C','0D','0E','0F'],
     ['01','02','03','04','05','06'],
     ['07','08','09','10','11','12'],
     ['13','14','15','16','17','18'],
     ['19','20','21','22','23','24']]

from itertools import chain
result = [M[0][:3]] + list(chain(*[[x[:2] + [y] for y in x[2:]] for x in M[1:]]))
```

Afterwards, `result` is

```
[['0A', '0B', '0C'],
 ['01', '02', '03'],
 ['01', '02', '04'],
 ['01', '02', '05'],
 ...
 ['19', '20', '23'],
 ['19', '20', '24']]
```

Comment: Perfect! I will adapt the code to my real problem (which is much higher) and put the feedback to colleagues who have the same challenge !! thank you all !!

Answer (score 0):

```
[row[:3] for row in my_table]
```

will give you just the first 3 columns

alternatively I guess you could transpose it to columns get the first 3 and then transpose it back

```
transposed_table = zip(*my_table)
my_cols = transposed_table[:3]
transposed_back_to_rows = zip(*my_cols)
```

or if you really want it on one line

```
zip(*list(zip(*my_table))[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using `numpy` library , you can use slicing to achieve this easily -

Example -

```
import numpy as np

n = np.array([['0A','0B','0C','0D','0E','0F'],
['01','02','03','04','05','06'],
['07','08','09','10','11','12'],
['13','14','15','16','17','18'],
['19','20','21','22','23','24']])

print('n - ' + str(n))

n1 = np.append(n[:,:3],n[:,3:], axis = 0)

print('n1 - ' + str(n1))
```

Output -

```
n - [['0A' '0B' '0C' '0D' '0E' '0F']
 ['01' '02' '03' '04' '05' '06']
 ['07' '08' '09' '10' '11' '12']
 ['13' '14' '15' '16' '17' '18']
 ['19' '20' '21' '22' '23' '24']]
n1 - [['0A' '0B' '0C']
 ['01' '02' '03']
 ['07' '08' '09']
 ['13' '14' '15']
 ['19' '20' '21']
 ['0D' '0E' '0F']
 ['04' '05' '06']
 ['10' '11' '12']
 ['16' '17' '18']
 ['22' '23' '24']]
```

Comment: very cool, but only the first 2 columns must repeat, the other columns are columns of date and just want a date column, so I repeat the first 2 columns of the row for each date column